# How to export ./getFirestore from package?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

ERROR in ./src/firebase.config.js 5:0-53

> Module not found: Error: Package path ./getFirestore is not exported
> from package
> C:\Users\pc\Documents\react\housemarketplace\node_modules\firebase
> (see exports field in
> C:\Users\pc\Documents\react\housemarketplace\node_modules\firebase\package.json)

Hi, I'm new to ReactJs. I am using firebase but facing this error. Here is my firebase.config.js code.

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {getFirestore} from "firebase/getFirestore"

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyDhcFQaKpAGkouNkk-Rs8dJsXkDhQyKPDA",
authDomain: "housemarketplace-66bcf.firebaseapp.com",
projectId: "housemarketplace-66bcf",
storageBucket: "housemarketplace-66bcf.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "453550391960",
appId: "1:453550391960:web:8ea1565a94d158e4e006ed"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export const  db = getFirestore()
```

Comment: Its `import {getFirestore} from "firebase/firestore"` and not `"firebase/getFirestore"`